# Python: is it possible to link two variable belonging to two different classes?

Tags: python, class

I would like to connect two variables totwo different classes but I don't know if what I'm trying to do is possible or not.

for instance, if I have those two classes:

```
class one():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def compute(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1


class two():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.C_one = one()
        self.link()

    def link(self):
        self.a = self.C_one.a

    def compute(self):
        self.C_one.compute()
        print('C_one a=',self.C_one.a )
        print('C_two a=',self.a )

C_two = two()
for i in range(5):
    C_two.compute()
```

In the class `two` I would like connect the variable `a` with the variable `a` of class `one`, so I don't have to explicitly call `self.a = self.C_one.a` each time I execute `C_two.compute`

The code in example give me this:

```
C_one a= 1
C_two a= 0
C_one a= 2
C_two a= 0
C_one a= 3
C_two a= 0
C_one a= 4
C_two a= 0
C_one a= 5
C_two a= 0
```

Which is not the result I expect.
Somebody know if I can do that in python?

### update

From the example below

```
class one():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def compute(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1


class two():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

class three():
    def __init__(self):
        self.C_one = one()
        self.C_two = two()
        self.b = 0

    def compute(self):
        self.C_one.compute()
        #self.C_two.a = self.C_one.a
        print('C_one a=',self.C_one.a )
        print('C_two a=',self.C_two.a )

C_three = three()
for i in range(5):
    C_three.compute()
```

is it possible to use the answer of deceze and replace the commented line `#self.C_two.a = self.C_one.a`with a property ? Like that classes `one` and `two` are linked in the class `three`.

### answer from deceze

```
class one():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
    def compute(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1


class two():
    def __init__(self,one): 
        self.C_one = one

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.C_one.a

class three():
    def __init__(self):
        self.C_one = one()
        self.C_two = two(self.C_one)
        self.b = 0

    def compute(self):
        self.C_one.compute() 
        print('C_one a=',self.C_one.a )
        print('C_two a=',self.C_two.a )

C_three = three()
for i in range(5):
    C_three.compute()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define `two.a` as a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class two:
    def __init__(self):
        self.C_one = one()

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.C_one.a

    ...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I updated the question because I wonder if we can use our answer to connect two classes in a third (like in the second example)?

Comment: The issue there is that `two()` creates its own `one()` unconnected to the `one()` you instantiate in `three()`. The solution there is *dependency injection*: `two(self.C_one)`.

Comment: So In the second example I must create a direct connection between class `one()` and `two() (and vise versa). So I must create and instance of `one()` in the `__init__()` of two (and vise versa)?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, it's bad practice to create instances of other classes inside an `__init__`. Instead you should do `def __init__(self, one): self.C_one = one`. Then you'll have exactly *one* place where you do `one()`, and you pass that one and only instance as constructor argument to any other class that needs it. → That's called *dependency injection.*

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will check that dependency injection that I wasn't aware of.